# Haskell - Calculate complex sum using lists

Tags: list, haskell

for a given list by user `s=[x1,x2,...,xk]` I need to calculate the sum of

```
x1 * (x2+x3+...x4)
+ (x1+x2) * (x3+x4+...xk)
+ ...
+ (x1+x2+...+x(k-2)) * (x(k-1) + xk)
+ (x1+x2+...+x(k-1)) * xk
```

from a function `[Int]->Int`

Please see the math formula in the following photo for better understanding :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yse91.jpg

just tried very little things like calculating the sum of the list minus the last element. **By the way i must implement all of this by using lists and very basic functions (head, tail ,init )**

```
xsum :: [Int] -> Int
xsum s = sumIntList (init s)

sumIntList :: [Int] -> Int 
sumIntList (h:t) = h + sumIntList t
sumIntList [] = 0
```

some of the result that SHOULD be produced by the calling of the function are :

```
xsum [4,5,8]
124

xsum [1..100]
341665830
```

Thanks for reading !

Comment: `xsum s = sum (zipWith (*) (map sum (inits s)) (map sum (tails s)))`

Comment: Thanks again for your input! As i said above i cant implement it using the functions like zipWith and map (also sum), cause i must only use very basic functions. But ill see if i can do something with the code you provided ! :-)

Comment: Sure, the source code for all of those functions are open to the public, so you can just copy and paste to reimplement the functions that aren't available to you.

Comment: you hid your requirement in the middle of a lengthy post. :) I didn't see it. perhaps it should have been **emphasized** in some way....?

Comment: what is the question? there is no question.

Comment: yes youre right thanks for the edit , im still new to this and haskell. The question is to implement the formula as seen in the picture using basic functions. Ive posted some desired results at the end. Also im using hugs :-(

Comment: Are you sure the desired results are correct? I *think*  `xsum [4,5,8] = 124` according to the formula you gave.

Comment: oh another mistake youre right , yes its 124 , forgive me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image you provided says `*` rather than `^`. It would be good to see some of your attempts. One simple approach would be to map the function `splitAt` across each possible index, then use the function `sum` on each pair to get the (initial segment sum, final segment sum) pair, then for each pair multiply its elements together, then sum all the resulting products. How far can you get with coding that up?

EDIT: to save potential future readers from scrolling through all the comments, a potential implementation is given below that uses only `sum`. It is suboptimal because it `sum`s the same sublists many times over, a better implementation might start by using `scanl` in both directions to generate the partial sums and proceed from there.

```
xsum (x:xs@(y:ys)) = x * sum xs + xsum ((x+y):ys)
xsum _ = 0
```

EDIT2: We have a (sort of) forwards-travelling and backwards-travelling thing going on, I like it!

```
xsum = fst . xsum'
  where xsum' (x:xs@(y:ys)) = (\(acc,s) -> (acc + x * (s-x),s) ) $ xsum' ((x+y):ys)
        xsum' [] = (0,0)
        xsum' [x] = (0,x)
```

Comment: yes the ^ is my mistake , the correct symbol its * , a fellow stackoverflower here made and edit on that thank god. Not far but i will try. Also because its a school assignment i cant use those functions even sum , if you see in the code that i posted i created one myself.

Comment: Indeed, but each of the few functions I mentioned is simple to implement, and it may be easier to build it out of these simple blocks (where you can peek at the prelude implementation if needed!). Although, there is also be a straight-up recursive definition which isn't too complicated. If you show your attempts we can give incremental hints.

Comment: ok ill try and i will send feeback if i acomplish anything. Im worried cause im fairly new to this , only twoo weeks in class with haskell and they presented us with those problems.

Comment: `xsum (x:xs@(y:ys)) = _` `xsum _ = _` see if you can fill in the right-hand-sides of these definitions for the recursive solution. The only other function you'll need for this is `sum` which you've already (correctly) defined. My hint is that I've already pattern-matched on the values you'll need (ie.. the clean way of writing it mentions all of `x, xs, y, ys`)

Comment: @A Tayler i tried   xsum(x:xs@(y:y s)) = x * ( sumIntList xs ) + (x + y) * (sumIntList ys)
    xsum [2] = 0
    xsum [1] = 0
    xsum [] = 0 , but only works for the first one . Sorry i coudnt formatted as code

Comment: You're close. The first part is correct, `(x+y)*...` is not, you will need a recursive call to `xsum`.

Comment: i thought about     xsum (x:xs@(y:ys)) = x * ( sumIntList xs ) + xsum xs    but i get an error. I should also make a guard so that when the elements of the list are under 2 , we get a 0

Comment: You will need `x+y`. Add the current item into the head of the remainder of the list then make the recursive call on the resultant list. Yes, you will need `xsum _ = 0` as a second line. You're really close!

Comment: again i tried xsum (x:xs@(y:ys)) = x * ( sumIntList xs ) + (x+y) + (xsum xs)  for the first line and xsum ys 
      | length ys < 2
         = 0                               for the second . I must be missing smthing

Comment: For the first line `xsum (x:xs@(y:ys)) = x * sumIntList xs + xsum ((x+y):ys)` , for the second line just `xsum _ = 0` because `_` catches all other cases which is what we want. The resulting implementation is not ideal because we're calling `sumIntList` across `tails` and the results are highly shareable, but it's simple and uses no extra functions. A better implementation would use a `scanl` front-to-back and back-to-front to generate the partial prefix-/suffix sums, zip them together, multiply the pairs, and sum the result.

Comment: wow great works fine . the xsum ((x+y):ys) part for me it too difficult to come up with though .but yeah good job

Comment: you don't need `scanl`. use same trick that you do with `(x+y)` -- save the first `sum xs` and then do `(sum - y)` as you move to the right. You will need an additional argument. I.e. if `sum (y:ys) = s`, then `sum ys = s - y`. Nice job. :)

Comment: Huh, cool idea. Though, if you're willing to fiddle with the top-level structure (such as by adding a helper function / argument) then it's easy to do the summing manually because you're recursing on the list, otherwise you summing it and then subtracting back down to 0.